# Store Type<B> in a Type<A> variable, where B extends A

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Given the example below, is it possible to add the `definition` to the list of `definitions`?

```
interface BaseArgs {
  name: string;
}

interface Definition<Args extends BaseArgs = BaseArgs> {
  args: Args;
  fn: (args: Args) => void
}

const definitions: Definition[] = [];

function addDefinition<Args extends BaseArgs>(definition: Definition<Args>) {
  definitions.push(definition);
  //               ^^^ compile error
}
```

This produces a compile error:

> Argument of type 'Definition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Definition'.
> Types of property 'fn' are incompatible.
> Type '(args: Args) => void' is not assignable to type '(args: BaseArgs) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
> Type 'BaseArgs' is not assignable to type 'Args'.
> 'BaseArgs' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Args', but 'Args' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseArgs'

I understand the part about *"Type 'BaseArgs' is not assignable to type 'Args'"*, however I'd expect that since I'm trying to store things the other way around, (`Args` in a `BaseArgs`) and `Args extends BaseArgs`, I should be able to do this.

I cant specify a generic type parameter (other than the default `BaseArgs`) when declaring `definitions: Definition[]` because the intention is for this to store definitions with many different types of `Args`, where all `Args` will extend `BaseArgs`

I *could* remove the generic type from the `addDefinition` function, which would allow this to complile, e.g.

```
function addDefinition(definition: Definition) {
  definitions.push(definition);
}
```

However I want to have intellisense for the definition properties when calling addDefinition, e.g:

```
interface CustomArgs extends BaseArgs {
  age: number;
}

function customFn(args: CustomArgs) { }

addDefinition({
  fn: customFn, 
  args: {
    // prompts for age (CustomArgs)
    // prompts for name (BaseArgs)
  }
});
```

The only alternative I can think of is to do the hacky casting, which always feels wrong (and probably *is* wrong!), e.g.

```
definitions.push(definition as unknown as Definition);
```

What other options do I have here?

Comment: Your code is wrong because functions are *contravariant* in their input types.  A function expecting an `Args` input could explode if passed a `BaseArgs` instead, so `(x: Args) => void` is not a valid `(x: BaseArgs) => void`.  Your code naturally wants *existentially quantified generics* which are not directly supported.  Given an array of definitions, can you do *anything* but call them with their args?  If not, then you might as well only expose that functionality like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/Wo1lMN) shows.  If so, then please [edit] to show a [mre]. Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I found this very helpful. In short, yes your suggested approach is suitable for what I was trying to achieve. I think the types in your comment are not completely aligned with the types in my post, which I found a bit confusing (`Args` in my case is a generic type param that extends `BaseArgs`), so when you say _"A function expecting an `Args` input could explode if passed a `BaseArgs` instead"_ isnt true going by my code. But I think I get what you mean.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is that `Definition<Args>` is *invariant* in `Args`, and thus `Definition<T>` cannot be assigned to `Definition<U>` unless `T` and `U` are the same type. (Combining the covariant `args` property and the contravariant `fn` property yields an invariant type.  See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for definitions of variance terminology.)

To see why this is the case, note that your `Definition` type without a type argument is equivalent to `Definition<BaseArgs>`.  Therefore, given a value `d` of type `Definition`, the compiler will allow you to write `d.fn({name: "xyz"})` with no error:

```
const definitions: Definition[] = [];
// ⋯
definitions.forEach(d => d.fn({ name: "xyz" })); // this is allowed
```

Now imagine you have a `Definition<T>` for some `T extends BaseArgs`, such as:

```
const myDef: Definition<{ name: string, age: number }> = {
  args: { name: "abc", age: 123 },
  fn(a) { console.log(a.age.toFixed()) }
}
```

Should you be allowed to push `myDef` onto `definitions` like this?

```
definitions.push(myDef) // error!
//  Type 'BaseArgs' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; age: number; }'.
```

No!  Because if you did this and called the `definitions.forEach()` above, there will be a runtime error of the form `a.age is undefined`.  It is not safe to assign `Definition<T>` to `Definition` when all you know is that `T extends BaseArgs`.

That explains the error.  But how do we fix it?

---

Really what you want to do here is say that `definitions` is an array of elements of type `Definition<T>` where `T` is *some* subtype of `BaseArgs`, and where each `T` can be different and you don't actually care what it is. So you'd want `T` to be what is known as [an *existentially quantified* generic type parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types).  TypeScript doesn't directly support such types (and neither do most languages with generics) although there is a feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  TypeScript's generic type parameters are *universally quantified*, meaning that anything dealing with a `Definition<T>` for generic `T extends BaseArgs` has to work with *all* subtypes of `BaseArgs`.

In an alternate universe where TypeScript had direct support for existential generics, you might be able to write

```
// Not valid TypeScript, do not try this:
const definitions: Array<<∃T extends BaseArgs>Definition<T>> = [];
```

But we can't.  Luckily, existential generics can be emulated by inverting control flow in a `Promise`-like fashion.  It looks like this:

```
interface SomeDefinition {
  run<R>(cb: <T extends BaseArgs>(d: Definition<T>) => R): R;
}

const definitions: SomeDefinition[] = [];
function addDefinition<T extends BaseArgs>(definition: Definition<T>) {
  definitions.push({ run(cb) { return cb(definition) } });
}
```

Essentially when you have a `SomeDefinition`, the `Definition<T>` is hidden away from you so that you cannot directly access it.  Instead you pass a callback `cb` which accepts it, and the callback will be run for you and the result handed back to you.  Your callback must therefore be able to handle any possible `T extends BaseArgs`.  So now this works:

```
const myDef: Definition<{ name: string, age: number }> = {
  args: { name: "abc", age: 123 },
  fn(a) { console.log(a.age.toFixed()) }
}
addDefinition(myDef);
```

If you try to do the bad thing and call `d.fn({name: "xyz"})` it will fail because `{name: string}` cannot be guaranteed to match the hidden generic:

```
definitions.forEach(sd => sd.run(d => d.fn({ name: "xyz" }))); // error!
// Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
```

Instead, you'll need to call `d.fn(d.args)` for it to work:

```
definitions.forEach(sd => sd.run(d => d.fn(d.args))); // okay
```

So that's one approach.

---

Of course, given `Definition<T>` for unknown `T`, there really isn't much you might do with it other than `d.fn(d.args)`.  If so, there's not much point supporting arbitrary callbacks.  You might as well make `run()` accept no args at all and just call `d.fun(d.args)` no matter what:

```
interface SomeDefinition {
  run(): void;
}

const definitions: SomeDefinition[] = [];

function addDefinition<T extends BaseArgs>(definition: Definition<T>) {
  definitions.push({ run() { definition.fn(definition.args) } });
}
```

And that gives you this:

```
const myDef: Definition<{ name: string, age: number }> = {
  args: { name: "abc", age: 123 },
  fn(a) { console.log(a.age.toFixed()) }
}
addDefinition(myDef);
definitions.forEach(sd => sd.run());
```

Or maybe you want to allow access to `args` also:

```
interface SomeDefinition {
  run(): void;
  args: BaseArgs;
}

const definitions: SomeDefinition[] = [];

function addDefinition<T extends BaseArgs>(definition: Definition<T>) {
  definitions.push({
    run() { definition.fn(definition.args) },
    args: definition.args
  });
}
```

The point here is that you can tweak `SomeDefinition` to expose only the functionality you need, instead of full-on emulation of existential generics.  A general callback-accepting `run()` might be overkill and confusing for consumers unfamiliar with existentials or who might wonder why you're treating a synchronous value like a `Promise`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QIJQOYbIDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMhmFKHgNzkC+55oksRCgAiEGKGBhgAexAAebMggAPSCAAmhdFlwFkAXjSYc+DAD5i5SnFONsnCshghGAChsE7ASgMWAbtLA6ty8ZNR0GAAOQkbqlo4IsszI6mISUkmMouIgkjIgANoAugbIxQ6UiSDJNACe2VlpuRnyRFS0DEwsbAA0yHB4nSAArjQARtDIXBaGpI7WtsTtdIwARHBjCKt9A50AjABMAMxTPVaUTiDuPm1VGNIANhAAdA-SeO7Pu89g0gBiwGUEHUri8Ph4jghlFSOTySWekWGGAAFq46tkfAB6TFKKBQaRQACE52xlAAKrVIigAOTaEwEanIYCEEDSMD9DAYYB4ahjJ7IX4Cyk0trhTrMVggDj9QaMEbjaDsKbU56hSgsWrxC4pJpw6rPGAEgCiiFRcX0FnUBquoo6a2k0kiXOBDvUT1WUzBStJEwQcCRKDAyOZyAAkgBlfoPN4Ad2B5y4yD9YAQyOQrmgUBu50qSUeLzeH0zXm9ONQAFUycgjQANAAKABkAPLCI2R7BVgBK5YAcmTQwBZI3IGOSNNwL6DJmEYYaJrxyGhCHkMVRGJG5TMtRSOAPcPAGjDB5wSBa5CkpNJdkw9L5DB2PFwWpyOSAYCIqyo1JojFgPOZsreshyGSZgzGURQOOc-DQPASDIOG0h0ABzT5GelBQLOcidmYrgIGMjDAUoqgQBoWjGLo5iuOojSwi0wFmD4FrIJ2XiMJ2FRTOcdzXrqLT3vBiEQMherFKU5TnDAs4IC0-TqOowl0R+xGkT+9KUTeKGyDRgHyCB2bzDqtF3giSKom0GFXHhNzIFAEBgMMUAgEmYxUbx+Tgp6HFQpe1TsuiYjaZprTLOK3RSjsspUKMExQFMYFzNqf6MLaKzIOsmzbDK+zHKcOaXNcSx3PmrzvJ83y-ACQIgmCnGLo4cByQp+RovUYglucGpoYZOkYAaxqmq4GDmhYQ3PBZVG+Ck1quClnSrMotQAF4elwYIlueOJBiGIasjGKTMrusYLtqpK6KMJHstIMBClSyDUrNjASmwSpcIyO1shyXI8hs-KCtEUAdAIyBXTdNJkiqCZJieqbphA1neRpeq9YaUAmqmg3DUwVrjZjVrOFRXymGtpbAwA1k+oQhGQfDgDBMQIUhbmyGe42scgARBBxSWqRRDjLmQ3HdUF-EM0JTOFCUhjidTZCSSA0moQ18ni4Rn4kd+dIUThiMtIFer0fp0Li71iIojNeWs0sOv5NN1uyITBDgmcBnc3bIAOxgCbtWQ-OC-5MB63RD1dJKeARUM0WTNMpQJf0izB+lWzh4whwnFwzuUPjcDWUVTwlR8E7lf8gLAqC4JU0rTWyC1GIOG7yP9ejQ2TaNrPreQQA)

Comment: Sorry I meant to come back to this sooner. Thanks for a very detailed answered. Your explanation helped me understand why this is the case, and your suggestion was suitable for what I was trying to achieve. Much appreciated!